# How can I assign a reflect.Value that holds an error object to an ordinary variable of type error?

Tags: go, reflection

I am trying to write a function that returns back to its caller an error result taken from the result slice of `reflect.ValueOf(somefunc).Call(someargs)`.

I've tried numerous variants of refer. calls, and type assertions. but cannot seem to get the compiler to let me put the actual concrete value from the `reflect.Value` slice back into an ordinary error variable.

Here's the code, using `os.Getwd` as the function:

```
   var somefunc interface{}
   var errToCaller *error
   somefunc = os.Getwd
   ftype := reflect.TypeOf(somefunc)
   errType := reflect.TypeOf(errToCaller).Elem()
   resType := ftype.Out(1)
   fmt.Println("resType.Implements(errType) = ",
      resType.Implements(errType))
   res := reflect.ValueOf(somefunc).Call([]reflect.Value{})
   fmt.Printf("res[1] as %%v = %v\n", res[1])
   fmt.Printf("res[1] as %%#v = %#v\n", res[1])
   fmt.Printf("ValueOf(res[1]) as %%v = %v\n",
      reflect.ValueOf(res[1]))
   fmt.Printf("ValueOf(res[1]) as %%#v = %#v\n",
      reflect.ValueOf(res[1]))
   fmt.Printf("ValueOf(res[1]).Type() as %%#v = %#v\n",
      reflect.ValueOf(res[1]).Type())
   fmt.Printf("ValueOf(res[1]).Interface() as %%#v = %#v\n",
      reflect.ValueOf(res[1]).Interface())
   // *errToCaller = reflect.ValueOf(res[1])
   // *errToCaller = reflect.ValueOf(res[1]).Interface()
   // *errToCaller = reflect.ValueOf(res[1]).Interface().(error)
```

With the following output:

```
resType.Implements(errType) =  true
res[1] as %v = <nil>
res[1] as %#v = error(nil)
ValueOf(res[1]) as %v = <error Value>
ValueOf(res[1]) as %#v = reflect.Value{typ:(*reflect.rtype)(0x4b9a60), ptr:(unsafe.Pointer)(0xc42000a3f0), flag:0x94}
ValueOf(res[1]).Type() as %#v = &reflect.rtype{size:0x18, ptrdata:0x10, hash:0x500c1abc, tflag:0x7, align:0x8, fieldAlign:0x8, kind:0x19, alg:(*reflect.typeAlg)(0x4a62d0), gcdata:(*uint8)(0x4daa41), str:21371, ptrToThis:184032}
ValueOf(res[1]).Interface() as %#v = error(nil)
```

I've abbreviated the example to remove lots of other Printf statements that indicate (to me at least) that the types are the same (even in what I think are the relevant fields of the `reflect.Value` struct).  **Why, when all of the various print statements seem to be telling me the result is an error value, can't I assign it to my local variable?**

Uncommenting the first assignment in the code example above results in this complaint from the compiler:

```
./passerror.go:30: cannot use reflect.ValueOf(res[1]) (type reflect.Value) as type error in assignment:
        reflect.Value does not implement error (missing Error method)
```

So I figured I needed the Interface() result, but still no luck (using the 2nd assignment commented out above):

```
./passerror.go:31: cannot use reflect.ValueOf(res[1]).Interface() (type interface {}) as type error in assignment:
        interface {} does not implement error (missing Error method)
```

Finally, a type assertion on the Interface() return value causes a panic:

```
panic: interface conversion: reflect.Value is not error: missing method Error
```

No matter what I've tried, I can't seem to escape from the dreaded `reflect.Value` which prevents me from doing the assignment to ordinary error variable.  I have tried `Set()` also without success, but perhaps incorrectly.

I would be forever grateful for insight and/or the magic incantation to do this.

**EDIT**
Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva for the spot on comment.  The code requires a real error variable, not just a *error, after which `localerr = res[n].Interface().(error)` worked perfectly.  (also changed function to os.Chdir using a bogus argument to trigger a non-nil error value)

Comment: Dave, `reflect.ValueOf(x)` is not the same as `reflect.ValueOf(reflect.ValueOf(x))`. Just do `res[1].Interface().(error)`. https://play.golang.org/p/caS0GQ-9b3

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Your example is not quite the same though, and if I change the return statement to `return nil` I get a panic:

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so good at formatting a comment.  That should have continued: `reflect.Value <nil>
<nil> <nil>
panic: interface conversion: interface is nil, not error
`

Comment: Use `err, _ := res[1].Interface().(error)` to avoid the panic on nil errors.

Comment: Of course, thanks.  I had removed that early on because it masks the behavior of the other mistaken approaches I used.  I was too quick on my earlier response.  Thanks so much for SO and the gracious folks who contribute!  Is it useful for @mkopriva to post an official answer so I can mark as accepted?  I'm not seeing how to upvote the comment  by mkopriva containing the answer...

Comment: Since you've already got this working @Dave this might be irrelevant, but please note that you declared `var errToCaller *error` and without ever setting `errToCaller` to an allocated pointer value, you later try to dereference it `*errToCaller = ...` which is not gonna work, even if everything else was fine your program would panic on those lines. The reason for this is because in Go you *cannot dereference `nil` pointers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned from [Call](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call) is a slice of `reflect.Value`s, so there is no need to wrap the result in another `reflect.ValueOf` call like you do in your example code:

```
reflect.ValueOf(res[1]) // not what you want
```

Doing that will change the value's underlying type from `error` to `reflect.Value` which is the reason why subsequently calling `.Interface().(error)` causes the program to panic.

So to fix your code just call `.Interface().(error)` directly on the result like so:

```
res[1].Interface().(error)
```

And, as already pointed out by [Cerise Limón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%c3%b3n), when you do *type assertion* it's good practice to use the "comma ok" idiom to avoid unnecessary panics.

```
err, ok := res[1].Interface().(error)
if !ok {
     // oops
}
```

Or, a bit more concise alternative:

```
if err, ok := res[1].Interface().(error); ok && err != nil {
     // it's a non-nil error
}
```